# Minimum regularity Of Stoke's theorem to hold in smooth manifold.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Stokes’ Theorem on Manifolds is often express as follows:

Given a differential m-form $\omega$ whose support is the $C^{\infty}$ $m$-dimensional compact manifold ${\cal{M}}$ with boundary $\partial{\cal{M}}$ then
\begin{equation}
\int_{\cal{M}}d\omega=\int_{\partial\cal{M}}\omega.
\end{equation}
Also  Stokes' theorem says that this is a chain map from de Rham cohomology to singular cohomology.

My questions are:

What is the lowest regularity on a Sobolev Space or similar functional space we can assume on $\omega$?

Is there something similar to De-Rham cohomology in the low regularity setting?

Comment: Search for papers by Jenny Harrison in this topic. I do not remember the exact result though.